# Using "watch" to detect difference in value and write to a file

Tags: watch

I am trying to catch the cause of an intermittent %CPU spike in a server with the command:
watch -n .5 "ps aux | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 2"
where it displays the process with the highest %CPU every .5 seconds.

However since it is difficult to catch (the event is random and I have no idea how long it lasts), I want to do the following:
1. Reduce the interval (to increase the chance of catching the event) and write the output to a file
2. Since the top process is usually constant anyway, I would like to write only when there is a difference in value between two succeeding outputs (like when the CPU spike occurs) to avoid creating such a huge file.

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Forget about watch, this should do, at least theoretically:

```
while true; do
  # I cut the header first with tail
  cat file <(ps aux | tail -n +2 | sort -rk 3,3 | head -n 2) | sort | uniq | sponge file
  # A certain amount of delay
  sleep 0.1
done
```

The only problem is that since CPU usage of each process varies over time, and what you are seeking for is particularly the CPU usage, the effect of `uniq` is very limited and still a large amount of data is produced. You can use `cut` to suppress the variables that are not important for you, so that their variation does not increase the number of data points produced.